# How do I preserve spaces in retrieving json keys?

Tags: json, vba, excel

I am using vba-json to parse json and am having trouble preserving spaces in keys. I am new to VBA and didn't see anything in the class to give me the option to preserve spaces in keys. 
I am using the class [found here](https://code.google.com/p/vba-json/issues/attachmentText?id=15&aid=150001000&name=jsonlib.cls&token=bzcFgbVHSfyx0aEDmmt70McRqd4%3A1367585799494)

I have:

```
Function me_()
    Dim s, json, i
    s = "{'key one':'value one','key two':'value two'}"
    Dim lib As New JSONLib
    Set json = lib.parse(CStr(s))

    For Each i In json
        Debug.Print i & "," & json.Item(i)
    Next
    me_ = "done"
End Function
```

This preserves the spaces in the values but not the keys:

```
keyone,value one
keytwo,value two
```

(jsonlint.com says my json is valid with the spaces in the keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by changing the code, specifically a method `parseKey`.

Whitespaces (spaces, tabs and various linebreaks) are ignored in keys on line `282`:

```
If InStr(vbCrLf & vbCr & vbLf & vbTab & " ", char) Then
```

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's due to syntax _features_ of `VB`, but e.g. in php or javascript `JSON` parsing functions takes 3-4 less lines.

Comment: yeah, easy for a Russian genius that retired at age 28 ;). Thanks!